# 'NSLog' is unavailable: Variadic function is unavailable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslog

I'm new to swift. when I'm learning just basics I got this error at `NSLog`

**Here is my code :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
     var myString: NSString?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myString = "himanth"
        print(myString)
        NSLog("%@" , myString)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

If I am declaring `myString` like this

```
var myString: NSString!
```

It's fine to use `NSLog` and I can able to see console as well.

But declaring string like this causing problem

```
var myString: NSString?
```

It reflects at `NSLog` and showing error.

What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you declare `var myString: NSString?` as an optional then you need to make sure it has a value before you pass it to the `NSLog`.

So you could do it like this then `NSLog("%@" , myString!)`. If `myString` is nil and you put `!` the program will crash and you will get

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
```

But if it has a value the program will continue as normal and print out

```
2016-10-03 10:26:25.077 Swift3.0[65214:1579363] Test
```

I wrote `myString = "Test"`.

Another example as [@Grimxn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3729417/grimxn) mentioned is the coalescing operator.

```
NSLog("%@", myString ?? "<nil>")
```

Comment: Better to use `NSLog("%@", myString ?? "<nil>")` surely?

Comment: That´s absolutely an alternative @Grimxn

Answer (score 19):

`NSLog()` cannot print Swift Optionals.

```
let optional: String?
NSLog("%@", optional) // 'NSLog' is unavailable: Variadic function is unavailable

let nonOptional: String
NSLog("%@", nonOptional) // Ok!

NSLog("%@", optional ?? "value-if-nil") // Ok!
```

Fix by passing a non-optional value to `NSLog()` instead.

NOTE:

`print()` ***can*** print Swift Optionals.

Answer (score 3):

Have the same problem, accepted answer doesn't help.

```
func handleSomeResp(_ response: DataResponse<Any>) {
    NSLog("handle error: %@", response)
}
```

as you see, there is nothing about optionals. 
I guess it because of `<Any>`, and any type, unclear for NSLog, watch similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989081/issue-with-nslog-with-swift-3/39989236): . 
Edit this answer if you have a solution to parse generics for NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` does not support any types except `String`. You cannot pass, i.e. your custom struct / enum instance as NSLog variadic argument.

Instead use `description` variable to show up necessary details about your instance. Your class / struct / enum could conform `CustomStringConvertible` to unify the way to access `description` variable as well.