# Issue with NSLog with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

After migrating to Swift 3, I get an error when I try and do:

```
self.publicDB.save(listRecord, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in
        if let saveError = error {
            NSLog("There was an error saving the record: %@", saveError)
        }...
```

Can someone tell me why this is and what I can do produce an output with relative ease?

The error is `NSLog unavailable: variadic function unavailable`.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AdamPro13 see update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867667/nslog-statements-not-showing-for-ios-10-in-apple-configurator/39868101#comment67027314_39868101

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, despite the "variadic" red herring, is that we no longer get automatic bridging to an Objective-C type; you have to cross the bridge explicitly, yourself. Write `saveError as NSError` to get an Objective-C style object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The error message is extremely misleading.

Answer (score 7):

NSLog doesn't work with Swift Object and the error that passed by the completion handler is Error not NSError.

So change your code to

```
self.publicDB.save(listRecord, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in
        if let saveError = error as? NSError {
            NSLog("There was an error saving the record: %@", saveError)
        }...
```

or write your own implementation of Error that extend `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol

```
class MyError: Error, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "The cause of error is xxx"
    }
}
```

and then set the completion to emit `MyError` rather than `Error`

Comment: @matt Sorry I didn't mean to copy your answer, maybe it's better if I delete my answer and edit yours?

Comment: Alternatively: if you're coding in Swift, ditch `NSLog()` altogether and use `print()` :-)

Comment: No thanks, that wouldn't be better, in my view. And I don't think you've violated any law. :)

Comment: @NicolasMiari But sometimes there are good reasons to use NSLog. And the question is a fair one; I've run into this problem myself.

Comment: @matt Fair point. Haven't felt the need myself yet, but will look into it.

Comment: @NicolasMiari And the "variadic" in the error message is highly misleading. The problem is in fact that we no longer get automatic bridging to an Objective-C type; you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I know, right? Typical misleading Swift error message. However, I remember having to cast `String` to `NSString` explicitly before Swift 3 (e.g., with Security.framework). Never understood the details of when `String` can pass as `NSString` and when it can't. Perhaps it's because Keychain is a C API, and bridging with Swift types was an Objective-C-only feature?

Comment: @NikoAdrianusYuwono you would need to write the error as `if let saveError = error as NSError?`